# string check in bash with -z and -n

Tags: string, bash, conditional-statements

I made a mistake in test syntax in bash but now I want to understand what really happens in string check with `-n` and `-z`.
I wrote the following lines to get in `LINENUM` variable the line number from a `grep`. When the string is not found (there is only one in the file, for sure), the `LINENUM` variable is empty.

```
$ LINENUM=$(grep -w -n mystring myfile | cut -d: -f1)
$ echo --$LINENUM--
----
$ if [ -n $LINENUM ] ; then echo "Checked -n"; fi
Checked -n
$ if [ -z $LINENUM ] ; then echo "Checked -z"; fi
Checked -z
```

Then I realized I forgot the double quotes and then the following check gave to me:

```
$ if [ -n "$LINENUM" ] ; then echo "Checked -n"; fi
$ if [ -z "$LINENUM" ] ; then echo "Checked -z"; fi
Checked -z
```

So, in the former tests, where I forgot the double quotes, versus what did the if test check , really, since I got two positive checks from both `-n` and `-z` ?

Comment: If you use double brackets: `[[ ... ]]` there is no need to quote the variable - even if it has embedded spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the quotes, your test statement (with either operator, represented with `-X` here), reduces to

```
if [ -X ]; then echo "Checked -X"; fi
```

According to the POSIX standard, the one-argument form of `test` (which you now have here) is true if the argument is non-null. Since the literal string `-X` is non-null (it's not an operator anymore), it evaluates to true.

With the quotes, you get

```
if [ -X "" ]; then echo "Checked -X"; fi
```

Since the quotes force an empty 2nd argument, you have a 2-argument form of `test`, and `-X` (whether `-n` or `-z`) is properly recognized as a primary operator acting on the 2nd, null, argument.

Comment: Holy cats, this is a subtle distinction. I was surprised that, after shell expansion completes, the argument list would collapse to a single element in both cases, but according to [word splitting in the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html), _"Explicit null arguments (`""` or `''`) are retained and passed to commands as empty strings."_ So `-X ""` would indeed trigger the two-argument invocation of `test`.